# Грязь -> грязнить -> грязниться

Tags: словообразование

грязь -> грязнить -> грязниться

Почему не верно составлена словообразовательная цепочка?

грязь -> грязный -> грязнить

Верно ли составлена эта?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: грязь - гряз/н/ый - гряз/н/и/ть.

**Проверка семантики слов:**

ГРЯЗНЫЙ, 1. Покрытый грязью, содержащий грязь. ГРЯЗНИТЬ,  Делать грязным, пачкать.

**Проверка значений суффиксов:**

**Значение суффикса Н:** образует прилагательные с общим значением признака, относящегося к предмету.

**Значение суффикса И:** образует глаголы с общим значением действия, имеющего отношение к мотивирующему слову (существительному или прилагательному: вина - винить, соль -солить, черный - чернить, грязный - грязнить).

Неправильно: грязь - гряз/н/и/ть, так как здесь использованы сразу два суффикса, смысловое отношение меду  словами также не соответствует словарю.